# Two step index match in Excel

Tags: excel

I have got below table in Excel

```
Month   Place   Value
Jan-18  A       850
Jan-18  B       427
Jan-18  C       2141
Jan-18  L       2278
Jan-18  O       772
Feb-18  A       1021
Feb-18  B       423
Feb-18  C       1281
Feb-18  L       1755
Feb-18  O       740
```

And what I need to do is to get values per month per place into separte table that is only for one place.

So, for A the results would be:

```
Month   Place   Value
Jan-18  A       850
Feb-18  A       1021
```

I do not want to concatenate columns for vlookup and I can not get it working with index / match.

Comment: SUMIF or SUMIFS not working for you?

Comment: Sorry, are you looking to sort the data or just hand it a place and have the list of results returned? If there is more than one entry for the same date are you wanting the value summed or to return both entries separately?

Comment: Related post: https://superuser.com/questions/57157/can-i-split-a-spreadsheet-into-multiple-files-based-on-a-column-in-excel-2007

Comment: @Jeeped SUMIFs are fine but I try to use index / match without VBA. @ Glitch - results per place per Month as seen above.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
=INDEX(Table2[Value], AGGREGATE(15, 7, (ROW(Table2[Value])-ROW(Table2[#Headers]))/((Table2[Month]=[@Month])*(Table2[Place]=[@Place])), 1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well this wouldn't be concatenation:

```
=INDEX(ValueRange,MATCH(1,(Month=MonthRange)*(Place=PlaceRange),0))
```

As this is an array formula it is applied with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Array formula that uses concatenation would be:

```
=INDEX(ValueRange,MATCH(Month&Place, MonthRange&PlaceRange,0))
```

Finnaly, to avoid array formulas, there is `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ValueRange)*(Month=MonthRange)*(Place=PlaceRange))
```